# node API hook that can be used to alter fields before loaded by Views?

Tags: 7, views, nodes, hooks

I need to use a node API hook to alter some node content before it's displayed, in Drupal 7.

It just occurred to me though that if I used `hook_node_view()` it will not effect the output of a View that display's those nodes fields (right?).

I need to alter the fields in **both** the display of the node and the node's display in any views. Hopefull this can be done in one function, and not have duplicate code in both `hook_node_view()` and `hook_views_pre_render()` or `function hook_views_data()`whichever hook is used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple ways in which this could be achieved:

1. Override the field itself in your theme with [`template_preprocess_field()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21field%21field.module/function/template_preprocess_field/7.x).
2. If the customization is more towards the markup, you can directly achieve that by overriding the field template.
3. Or you could just write a [field formatter](https://www.metaltoad.com/blog/drupal-7-tutorial-creating-custom-formatters-field-api) for this field, and select it in the field settings of the views and the view-mode (manage display) of your content type.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't consider #1 because I don't have any experience doing that. I already have several custom module hooks so I thought I would just make another. I'll look into `template_preprocess_field` though, that might be just what I need. #2 won't work for me because, what I'm doing is I'm not displaying a field at all if certain conditionals are met. I did consider #3 and that would be very clean but maybe a little more effort. And if a field formatter is already selected for the field then can I have two field formatters for one field??

Comment: BTW, I need to alter the field for only certain node types and sometimes only when certain tags are chosen for that node type. Is it still possible to use template_preprocess_field for this?

Comment: @DanMantyla Yep! In the preprocess field you should be able to find the node with something like `$variables['element']['#object']` and then use any of its properties (type, status, published, etc) or even field values.